# customised comparator in not working

Tags: android, listview, comparator

I am using `Comparator` to sort my `ListView`, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
Collections.sort(orgi, new Comparator<Loc>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Loc lhs, Loc rhs) {

                    if( lhs.getDist() < rhs.getDist() )
                         return 1;
                      else
                         return 0;
                }
            });
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What is return type of getDist()? And what is not working

Comment: Please post the code of `Loc` class, and you can't sort `ListView`, I guess you meant `ArrayList` or `List`.

Comment: BTW you must return a value < 0 as well because according to docs compare should return "an integer < 0 if lhs is less than rhs, 0 if they are equal, and > 0 if lhs is greater than rhs"

Comment: @PankajKumar return type is double.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh its arraylist.ArrayList<Location> orgi;
   orgi = new ArrayList<Location>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(orgi, new Comparator<Loc>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Loc lhs, Loc rhs) {
                if(lhs.getDist() < rhs.getDist()){
                     return -1;
                 } else if(lhs.getDist() > rhs.getDist()){
                     return 1;
                 } else {
                     return 0;
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now :).. i was returning the wrong values. am such a dumb ;P. thanks.

Comment: @user2978175 I am glad that your problem was solved but simply thanking is not the way to go on Stackoverflow. You must accept one of the answers if it helped you.